# PSTricks segment orientation

Tags: pstricks

I want to make a simple 3D picture in PStricks (showing how to measure a segment starting at the origin in the space). The main issue is to properly draw the projections of the defining point A along the axes. As shown in the picture below, my idea was to shift few projections of A (by means of the pstricks option `origin={}`). The problem is that pstricks does not make any difference between the segments OA and AO, which is crucial for my idea to apply. On the other hand, even by creating nodes at A and O is not possible to shift the `\ncline` AO.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1.5)(3.5,2.5)
    \psline[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(3.5,0)
    \psline[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(0,2.5)
    \psline[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(2;225)
    \psline[linecolor=teal]{-*}(2.5;20)
    %\pnodes(0,0){O}(1;225){A1}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=lightgray](0,0)(2.5;20|1;225)
    \psline[linestyle=dotted](1;225)(2.5;20|1;225)(2.5;20)
    \psline[linestyle=dotted,origin={2.5;20}](2.5;20|1;225)(0,0) % this is not PO
    \psline[linestyle=dotted,origin={2.5;20|1;225}](1;225)(0,0)% this is not QO
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

So, my question is how to make pstricks treat differently the segments AO and OA? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a coordinatewise way to draw the segments, without shifting them. Here is a solution (cf. the red dotted `psline`s), using the specialities of pstricks.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1.5)(4,2.5)
    \psline[linestyle=dotted](1;225)(2.5;20|1;225)(2.5;20)
    \psline[linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red](!90 cos 2.5 20 sin mul 225 sin sub)(2.5;20)
    \psline[linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red](2.5;20|1;225)(!225 cos neg 2.5 20 cos mul add 0 sin)
    \psline[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(4,0)
    \psline[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(0,2.5)
    \psline[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(2;225)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=lightgray](0,0)(2.5;20|1;225)
    \psline[linecolor=teal]{-*}(2.5;20)
\end{pspicture}
```

Anyway, my curiosity about the difference between segments AO and OA does persist, so if someone could explain me the way pstricks read them, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\psset{coorType=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1.5)(3.5,2.5)
\pstThreeDCoor
\pstThreeDLine[linecolor=teal,arrows=-*](0,0,0)(3,3,4)
\pstThreeDLine[linestyle=dotted](0,0,0)(3,3,0)
\pstThreeDLine[linestyle=dotted](3,0,0)(3,3,0)
\pstThreeDLine[linestyle=dotted](0,3,0)(3,3,0)
\pstThreeDLine[linestyle=dotted](3,3,0)(3,3,4)
\end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

or the same with 2d lines:

```
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1.5)(3.5,2.5)
    \psline[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(3.5,0)
    \psline[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(0,2.5)
    \psline[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(2;225)
    \psline[linecolor=teal]{-*}(2.5;20)
    %\pnodes(0,0){O}(1;225){A1}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=lightgray](0,0)(2.5;20|1;225)
    \psline[linestyle=dotted](1;225)(2.5;20|1;225)(2.5;20)
    \psline[linestyle=dotted](0,1.5)(2.5;20)
    \psline[linestyle=dotted,origin={3,0}](1;225)(0,0)
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Not precisely. I mean, I know that the pstrick's 3dplot package is meant to manage 3d pictures, but on the one hand I just need the above simple picture, so that I won't invoke that heavy package; on the other hand, I was more concerned in the way pstricks deals with the segment orientations. Thank you!

Comment: See edited answer ...